# Java Streams condition for tictactoe

Tags: java

this should be a tictactoe game but I will to wright it only with Java Streams.
Now it will be checked only for 3 duplicates allover and I need to check for duplicates which are horizontal vertical or diagonal (just normal condition for this game but wroten with Streams like in the below 2 solutions).

```
List<String> listTicTacToe = new ArrayList<>(List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"));
```

Solution 1:

```
List<String>res2 = listTicTacToe.stream()
        .filter(number -> Collections.frequency(listTicTacToe, number) == 3)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

isWinner = !res2.isEmpty();
```

Solution 2:

```
List<String> res = listTicTacToe.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 3)
                .map(e -> e.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible with using only Java Streams?

Comment: It is not clear how you are representing 3x3 board using a 1D List

Comment: Good point, the list can be modified.

Comment: You need to explain how your model of the board works. How exactly do the strings in the array in your question represent a tictactoe board? It's difficult to suggest ways of using streams to detect board conditions when it's unclear how the board is represented.

Comment: This is not given but it can be 2d ArrayList like this: `int vertexCount = 3;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listTicTacToe = new ArrayList<>(vertexCount);`

Comment: Lets assume we have a 2d arraylist and the data is already there as string. E.g. player x puts "X" to the array list and player o puts "O" and the solution is to find 3*X or 3*O vertical horizontal or diagonal

Comment: I don't see any benefit in using streams (performance wise as well readability wise)

Comment: If the new data comes e.g. over scanner then it will be checked. At the beginng the list could look like this `graph.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("1","4","7")));
        graph.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("2","5","8")));
        graph.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("7","8","9")));` and the numbers as string will be replaced by "X" or "O"

Answer (score 1):

If you have `3` (or more) values that correspond to a particular player on a board, it doesn't automatically mean that they form a weening combination (arranged in a line).

There should be a lot of conditional logic, so I am afraid it can't be done without imperative code. But you might incorporate some elements of the functional programming.

Here's a small illustration.

You can perform a check whether the previous move produced a weening combination using a stream.

***Note*** that there's no need to check all the possible combinations on a board. Only cells that are **adjacent** to the cell that the player has changed needs to be checked. Building on this idea, we can define a static array (make it a list if you don't want to use arrays, but array would be more convenient) containing offsets that represent 4 combinations of cell (horizontal `-`, vertical `|`, and two diagonal `\` and `/`).

We can iterate over the array representing cell-combination searching if there's at least one valid using [`Stream.anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)). Is that's the case, the player which made the last move has weened.

Here's how the implementation of this logic might look like (*as I've said it's not entirely functional in style*):

```
public class TicTacToe {
    public static final int[][][] NEIGHBOURS =
           {{{0, -1}, {0, 1}},   // horizontal -
            {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}},   // vertical |
            {{-1, -1}, {1, 1}},  // diagonal \
            {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}}; // diagonal /
    
    private List<List<String>> board = List.of( // Arrays.asList() is used for nested lists because it allows to modify values, but disallows structural modifications as well List.of()
        Arrays.asList("1", "4", "7"), // populate with any non-null values in order to perform `equals()` checks safely
        Arrays.asList("2", "5", "8"),
        Arrays.asList("3", "6", "9")
    );
    
    public boolean isWinningMove(int row, int col) {
        return Arrays.stream(NEIGHBOURS)
            .anyMatch(isWinningCombination(row, col));
    }
    
    public Predicate<int[][]> isWinningCombination(int row, int col) {

        return neighbour -> {
            int[] leftShift = neighbour[0];
            int[] rightShift = neighbour[1];
            String currentPlayer = getBoardValue(row, col);

            return getBoardValue(row + leftShift[0], col + leftShift[1])   // left Neighbour == current
                        .equals(currentPlayer)
                && getBoardValue(row + rightShift[0], col + rightShift[1]) // right Neighbour == current
                        .equals(currentPlayer);
        };
    }

    public String getBoardValue(int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= board.size() || col < 0 || col >= board.get(row).size()) { // invalid index
            return "INVALID INDEX"; // illegal value for which `isWinningCombination()` will return false
        }
        return board.get(row).get(col); // return the real value under the given coordinates
    }
}
```